# How do I avoid "Don't put any logic in createState"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code from a library I'm needing to use directly in my project.

```
  @override
  AFWidgetState<T> createState() => AFWidgetState<T>(
        formBuilder(),
        handleErrorOnSubmit: handleErrorOnSubmit,
        enableFinalAction: enableFinalAction,
        enableSubmitFormWrapper: enableSubmitFormWrapper,
      );
}

class AFWidgetState<T extends TemplateForm> extends AFFormState<AFWidget<T>, T> {
  AFWidgetState(
    T model, {
    ValueChanged<String>? handleErrorOnSubmit,
    required bool enableFinalAction,
    bool? enableSubmitFormWrapper,
  }) : super(
          model: model,
          handleErrorOnSubmit: handleErrorOnSubmit,
          enableFinalAction: enableFinalAction,
          enableSubmitFormWrapper: enableSubmitFormWrapper,
        );
```

I get this warning
**Don't put any logic in createState.**

I'm unable to figure out what to do, since 'super' is being called in the constructor and there is no way to access 'widget.' in constructors.

Comment: Why are you calling super on a state? What is `AFFormState` and why are you extending it?

Comment: From what I can understand the developer has opted for a way to split the state file. The AFFormState is like this:

abstract class AFFormState<T extends StatefulWidget, G extends TemplateForm> extends State<T> {
  `AFFormState({
    required this.model,
    this.enableFinalAction = true,
    this.handleErrorOnSubmit,
    this.enableSubmitFormWrapper,
  });`